# ServerSideRender not rendering in block editor, but output is in "apiFetch"

Tags: block-editor

I'm building a dynamic block. All seems to be working fine, except it isn't actually rendering the block in the editor. It is doing something, because if I inspect the page source in the editor, the content that should be being rendered is on the page, but it's inside of an apiFetch:

```
<script id="wp-api-fetch-js-after">
    ...
    wp.apiFetch.use(..."content":{"raw":" \\my html is here ","protected":false,"block_version":1},
    ...
```

My edit code looks like this:

```
  import ServerSideRender from '@wordpress/server-side-render';
  import { useBlockProps } from '@wordpress/block-editor';
  export default function Edit({ props }) {
    const blockProps = useBlockProps();
    return (
      <div {...blockProps}>
        <ServerSideRender
          block="cwr/testimonial-block"
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
```

Note, I'm not passing any attributes because there's nothing configurable. I also tried changing the import to

`const { ServerSideRender } = wp.components;`

but there was no difference.

Initially, the render function was outputting the desired HTML; however, that resulted in it getting directly inserted after the opening `<body>` tag on the editor page, and generating an error. Based on a StackOverflow question, I've now changed that so the render function is returning a string. Both methods rendered fine on the front-end.

Current render function:

```
function cwr_testimonial_render_callback( $block_attributes ) {

    $the_block = '<div class="testimonial-wrapper">No testimonials "
        . "found. Please create some first."</div>';

    // code to change the above default to the desired dynamic output

    return $the_block;
}
```

And registration is set up thusly:

```
function create_block_cwr_testimonial_block_block_init() {
    register_block_type( __DIR__ . '/build',
      array(
          'render_callback' => 'cwr_testimonial_render_callback',
      )
    );
}
add_action( 'init', 'create_block_cwr_testimonial_block_block_init' );
```

And my block.json:

```
{
        "$schema": "https://schemas.wp.org/trunk/block.json",
        "apiVersion": 2,
        "name": "cwr/testimonial-block",
        "version": "0.99.1",
        "title": "Simple Testimonial Block",
        "category": "widgets",
        "icon": "flag",
        "description": "A simple block for a testimonial slider",
        "attributes": {
                "message": {
                        "type": "string",
                        "source": "text",
                        "selector": "div"
                }
        },
        "supports": {
                "html": false
        },
        "textdomain": "cwr-testimonial-block",
        "editorScript": "file:./index.js",
        "editorStyle": "file:./index.css",
        "style": "file:./style-index.css"
}
```

What am I missing to get it to actually render in the editor?

Comment: Is this on WordPress v6? And your code looked good to me, so maybe you just need to clear your caches? If that doesn't help, can we see the full plugin source, maybe on GitHub?

Comment: Correct on both counts! I was running v6 (and didn't mean to be ... forgot to add a .wp-env.json), _and_ there was cruft in the build directory! Thanks @SallyCJ!